# jQuery isotope 2 check if is applied

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

i'm using isotope 2 (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and now i need to check if isotope is applied, or destroyed.

I need to destroy the applied isotope in the mobile size, so i do a

```
$container.isotope('destroy');
```

on windowResize, if the window width is less than 767.

After destroying, i need to check if isotope is active or destroyed.

In isotope v1 was the class "isotope" added, now there is no class in v2.

Any ideas?

best regards
CH